# SpringBoot deserialize a JSON array in Java using Jackson

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

I am currently writing a SpringBoot application that retrieves a JSON array from an external API.  The part of the JSON I need looks like:

```
{
"users": [
    "id": 110,
    "name": "john"
  ]
}
```

In my Controller I am doing the following:

```
 ResponseEntity<Users> response = restTemplate
    .exchange(url, headers, Users.class);

return response
```

I then have a Users class that looks like:

```
@JsonProperty("id")
public String id;
@JsonProperty("name")
public string name;
```

How can I access the information inside the JSON array?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading into a POJO based on your return type you need to accept list of Users.

You cannot accept List of user class in ResponseEntity you need to first cast into object class.

`ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate .exchange(url, headers, Object.class);`

Then you need to convert it into list of users.

`List<Users> usersList = (List<Users>) response.getBody();`

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you posted above is not correct. It needs to be:

```
{
   "users": [
       {
          "id": 110,
          "name": "john"
       }
    ]
}
```

and whatever object is used needs a list of `Users`.

The other thing is you `restTemplate` call is wrong, you are expecting the call to return `ResponseEntity<Opportunities>` class yet when in your `restTemplate` you are giving it the `User` class and that will return `ResponseEntity<User>` instead

Comment: Sorry these were editing mistakes when posting the code.  They do match what you have posted.